# Merge rows from same dataframe

Tags: r, merge

I was wondering if it would be possible to merge different rows on a dataframe if they have 1 field in common:

input:

```
df = rbind(c("01/01/2016",01:02:30,"100","character(0)","file A"),
           c("02/01/2016",9:02:30,"character(0)", 3, "file A"),
           c("02/01/2016",8:30:30,"200","character(0)","file B"),
           c("03/01/2016",8:25:30,"50","character(0)","file C"),
           c("04/01/2016",17:20:30,"character(0)","600","file B"))
```

output:

```
df = rbind(c(01/01/2016,01:02:30,"100",3,"file A"),
           c(02/01/2016,8:30:30,"200",600,"file B"),
           c(03/01/2016,8:25:30,"50","character(0)","file C"))
```

So as yo can see we merge the rows according to last value (file A, file B or file C).
I need to keep the earliest of the dates. eg for "file A" we have 2 dates 01/01/2016 and 02/01/2016, we want to keep the 
we won't merge more than 2 rows per value

We want to keep the earliest date

Comment: You can use the `dplyr::group_by` or `data.table`'s `by = ` and get `min()` values. BTW, your input and output examples throw warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments you want to find the first instance (ordered by one column) of a non-missing value for each column based on a grouping column (in your case the "file A/B/C" column).

First you will have to clean your data a bit. Your data load step is buggy due to some misplaced quotation marks around the timestamps. Also, I'm assuming you want to represent missing values with the `character(0)` values. If so use `NA`s. Here is the data initialisation and cleaning step:

```
# prepare your data
df = data.frame(V1 = c("01/01/2016 01:02:30","02/01/2016 9:02:30","02/01/2016 8:30:30",
                       "03/01/2016 8:25:30","04/01/2016 17:20:30"),
                V2 = c("100","character(0)","200","50","character(0)"),
                V3 = c("character(0)", "3", "character(0)","character(0)", "600"),
                V4 = c("file A", "file A", "file B", "file C", "file B"))

# replace the character(0)s with NAs as they are missing values
df[df == "character(0)"] <- NA

# convert character dates to time
df$V1 <- strptime(as.character(df[ ,1]), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I've named the columns `V1..4` but you probably want some more descriptive names. To get what you need you'll to fill up the missing values for of the columns by using the `zoo` package's `na.locf()` function. To eliminate the cross contamination of data across different values of `V4` column I'm looping through the data. (there might be a better solution to this...)
Here is a function to do your custom row merging:

```
custom_row_merge <- function(df,
                             sort_by,
                             group_by){

    # sort by dates in decreasing order
    df <- df[order(df[,group_by], df[,sort_by]), ]

    # select the columns to merge
    columns_to_merge <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% c(sort_by, group_by))]

    # fill data for each unique value of group by column
    for (file_type in unique(df[, group_by])){

        row_indices <- (df[,group_by] == file_type)

        # fill missing values for each column that is not group by or sort by
        for (column_name in columns_to_merge){

            df[row_indices, column_name] <- na.locf(df[row_indices, column_name],
                                                    na.rm = F,
                                                    fromLast = T)
        }    

    }

    # get first occurence of each file, now with the filled values
    return(df[!duplicated(df[, group_by]), ])

}
```

Here is the original data frame:

```
> df
                   V1   V2   V3     V4
1 2016-01-01 01:02:30  100 <NA> file A
2 2016-01-02 09:02:30 <NA>    3 file A
3 2016-01-02 08:30:30  200 <NA> file B
4 2016-01-03 08:25:30   50 <NA> file C
5 2016-01-04 17:20:30 <NA>  600 file B
```

And the one produced by the function, matching what you describe in your question:

```
> custom_row_merge(df, "V1", "V4")
                   V1  V2   V3     V4
1 2016-01-01 01:02:30 100    3 file A
3 2016-01-02 08:30:30 200  600 file B
4 2016-01-03 08:25:30  50 <NA> file C
```

You can of course fill the missing values with `characer(0)` values if you want to.

Comment: I get this: Error in df[, 1] <- strptime(df[, 1], format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros Have you tried my assignment of df? Your question has a typo in it where the H:M:S part of the time is separate and not commented. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros sorry, the data load step was buggy. See my updated answer.

Comment: sorry this doesn't help me I need to merge both rows, not just take the first one ...

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros oh okay. now i get it. But how do you want to handle dates? You want the first date and the first non missing value for each column, right?

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros Okay, updated my answer. Hopefully this will get what you want. ;) Let me know if not.